# Virt Manager: Windows vm don't see any networks

Tags: windows, kvm, qemu, virt-manager

Recently I have installed QEMU + Virt Manager so I can run some windows programs without leaving my linux. And I got stuck on network.
I have the `default` network with source set to `NAT` and device model set to `virtio`. and it's active.
I tied using `bridged` connection before but it just throw `Error starting domain: Cannot get interface MTU on 'win10vm': No such device` at start up.
Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows doesn't support `virtio` devices out of the box. You used to be able to download a virtio driver disk [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/creating-windows-virtual-machines-using-virtio-drivers/), but for licensing reasons that's no longer available.

The easiest alternative is to use a NIC model that is supported by Windows. Instead of `virtio`, consider using `e1000e`.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I couldn't setup bridge. It just says `Error starting domain: Cannot get interface MTU on 'win10vm': No such device`. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest opening a second question for that issue. When you do so, please provide enough information in the question for us to reproduce the problem: the specific commands and/or configuration that you're using.